# Trouble removing ruby 2.3.0p0 from Ubuntu

Tags: apt, uninstall, ruby, software-uninstall

I need to install ruby via rvm. I already have it installed via packet manager though, and now I want to remove that version.
So far so good, removing stuff with apt-get remove isn't hard. BUT
after I ran

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby
```

and then

```
ruby -v
```

I got this:

```
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
```

Why is that still there? I tried specifying the ruby version like this

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby2.3.0p0
```

(both with p0 at the end and without), but I just get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ruby2.3.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ruby2.3.0'
```

`which ruby` returns

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

`readlink -f /usr/local/bin/ruby` returns

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

aswell! Shouldn't the ruby version be at the end of that path?

I have read through a ton of threads on here, but nobody seemed to have the same problem as me. Ruby doesn't show up in the Software Center either. I'm not sure if I even need to remove this version before installing it again with rvm, but I'd still rather remove it.

I'd be glad if someone could help me remove ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use apt-get because  it contains a older version of ruby.
You can use `dpkg -r ruby2.3.0` .If you want to purge use `dpkg -P ruby2.3.0` 
Assuming thats the name of the package if you are not sure you can find out the name using `dpkg --list`

[Source](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/install-remove-deb-package/)

Comment: the only version of ruby I can find when using `dpkg --list` is ruby1.9.1
Tried removing 2.3.0 anyway, but I got this error: `dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove ruby2.3.0p0 which isn't installed` Again tried both with and without p0

Comment: did u install this from source??

Comment: Now that you mention it... I might have. I honestly can't remember.

Comment: U must have installed from source thats why its not listed.Just check if u still have the source in your system